# Upload a file to Azure Blobservice from a public URI

Tags: azure-storage

Is Microsoft planning on to create a method in Azure BlobService that fetches data to the storage from a public URI? Quick google search shows it [had something](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.windowsazure.storage.blob.cloudblob.startcopyfromblob.aspx) similar in the past, but API is outdated now.

Comment: Is there any updates about this thread? If it is useful, please help to marked it that will be more helpful for the communities who has the same issue.

Comment: Hey Tom, thank you, definitely helpful. A follow-up question: apparently Azure Python SDK has a bit different class hierarchy. What do you think is the best way to go about implementing this functionality in leu of CloudBlockBlob API? Or maybe there is a CloudBlockBlob source code that you can point us to, so we get an idea.

Comment: We can use  [CloudBlockBlob  Copy blob API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/fileservices/copy-blob) to do that. And the StartCopy function also implement  that API. I will update the test result in the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please have a try to use `CloudBlockBlob.StartCopy` or `CloudBlockBlob.StartCopyAsync`,it can work correctly. I write a demo for it.More info about the CloudBlockBlob.StartCopy please refer to the [article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.windowsazure.storage.blob.cloudblob.startcopy.aspx).

```
CloudStorageAccount storageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.Parse("Storage connection string");
CloudBlobClient blobClient = storageAccount.CreateCloudBlobClient();
CloudBlobContainer container = blobClient.GetContainerReference("newcontainer"); //container name
var source = new Uri("public file url");
CloudBlockBlob target = container.GetBlockBlobReference("targe blob name");
target.StartCopy(source);
//or target.StartCopyAsync(source).Wait();
```

**Update:**

I did a test with [copy blob api](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/fileservices/copy-blob), detail info please refer to the screenshot.

[image]

Comment: great update  - I know I could have checked the wire and see the call myself after your first update, but I'm too lazy. Thanks a lot!